# Why Is my data not being completely added to my array?

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, struct, strtok

I am trying to take the data from the CSV file output.csv using strtok and then print it out. However, when I print it out, it seems to split the last datapoints into 2 entries, with the second one being put in the next entry in the array.

```
time,identifier,x,y,z
2000.123,A123,2.849,0.34,-0.543
2001.456,A123,3.493,0.19,-0.987
2001.735,A123,5.403,1.587,0.579,-0.254
```

I'm reading the data and using a struct and an array to store it.

```
struct  Data {
double Time_Data;
char* ID;
double X_Data;
double Y_Data;
double Z_Data;
```

};

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char* field;
char line[50];
struct Data dataPoints[3567];
FILE * pointer;
fpointer = fopen("output.csv", "r");

if(fpointer == NULL){
    printf("Unable to open file \n");
    return 0;
}    
int LineCount = 0;
while(fgets(line, 30, fpointer) != NULL){

    field = strtok(line, ",");
    dataPoints[LineCount].Time_Data = atof(field);

    field = strtok(NULL, ",");

    field = strtok(NULL, ",");
    dataPoints[LineCount].X_Data = atof(field);

    field = strtok(NULL, ",");
    dataPoints[LineCount].Y_Data = atof(field);
    field = strtok(NULL, ",");
    dataPoints[LineCount].Z_Data = atof(field);

    LineCount++;
}


fclose(fpointer);


printf("%lf    %lf    %lf    %lf\n", dataPoints[0].Time_Data, 
dataPoints[0].X_Data,dataPoints[0].Y_Data, dataPoints[0].Z_Data);
printf("%lf    %lf    %lf    %lf\n", dataPoints[1].Time_Data, 
dataPoints[1].X_Data,dataPoints[1].Y_Data, dataPoints[1].Z_Data);
printf("%lf    %lf    %lf    %lf\n", dataPoints[2].Time_Data, 
dataPoints[2].X_Data,dataPoints[2].Y_Data, dataPoints[2].Z_Data);
printf("%lf    %lf    %lf    %lf\n", dataPoints[3].Time_Data, 
dataPoints[3].X_Data,dataPoints[3].Y_Data, dataPoints[3].Z_Data);
printf("%lf    %lf    %lf    %lf\n", dataPoints[4].Time_Data, 
dataPoints[4].X_Data,dataPoints[4].Y_Data, dataPoints[4].Z_Data);
printf("%lf    %lf    %lf    %lf\n", dataPoints[5].Time_Data, 
dataPoints[5].X_Data,dataPoints[5].Y_Data, dataPoints[5].Z_Data);

return 0;

}
```

The problem is that for some reason the Z_Data is being split into 2 and moved to the next entry in the array. The output I get is

```
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2000.123000    2.849000    0.340000    -0.500000
43.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2001.456000    3.493000    0.190000    -0.900000
87.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2001.735000    5.403000    1.587000    0.500000
```

Which I'm not really sure why it is happening.

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: The input lines are not longer than the buffer, but you restrict the length read to `30`, which is too small. Try `fgets(line, sizeof line, fpointer)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of each lines of your CSV file are:

```
time,identifier,x,y,z                  : 21 chars
2000.123,A123,2.849,0.34,-0.543        : 31 chars
2001.456,A123,3.493,0.19,-0.987        : 31 chars
2001.735,A123,5.403,1.587,0.579,-0.254 : 38 chars
```

You specified `30` as the buffer size for `fgets()`. This value is insufficient for reading the data lines.
The value should be `sizeof(line)` because you allocated 50 chars for `line` and using magic numbers should be avoided.